# What are Woodland Mansions in Minecraft 1.11? Where can I find them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

With the upcoming [1.11 Exploration update](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.11), there will be some new features added, including a new type of structure: **Woodland Mansion** (already available in the snapshots).

**What is a Woodland Mansion - do any mobs spawn in/aruond it? Where can I find it?**

Comment: Also related: [What types of rooms can I find in a woodland mansion?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288790/what-types-of-rooms-can-i-find-in-a-woodland-mansion-in-minecraft), [Where can I find chests in woodland mansions, and what can I find in them?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288979/where-can-i-find-chests-in-woodland-mansions-and-what-can-i-find-in-them)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some specifics of Woodland Mansions:

- It is a massive structure, up to cca. 65x65 blocks wide and 30 blocks high. It consists of three floors (the third is spaller) connected by a central staircase.
- **It can be found in Roofed Forest biomes**, and is very rare - I made a test using the command [`/locate`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#locate) and calculated the average distance from 10 worlds: In average, the Mansion is located 15000 blocks away from spawn. But, luckily, the structure is so big you won't miss it when passing by.
- The Mansion is home to [Illagers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Illager), which have two variants: [Vindicators](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Vindicator) and [Evokers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Evoker). Both are hostile, and Evokers can also spawn [Vexes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Vex).
- It consists of different types of rooms, usually with one entrance, eg. hallways, staircases, dinner rooms, etc. Because the Mansion is procedurally generated room by room, some rooms may have no entrances, or multiple entrances. Each room (except the staircase) takes up the same space - 7x7x7 blocks, discluidng the walls, floor and ceiling (which render after the rooms, accordingly to the rooms around them).

  - Warning: A chunk with a Mansion takes up about 15-20 times more time to generate than a normal chunk upon first load.
- It can be located using the [`/locate` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#locate) or with a [Exploration map](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Exploration_Map). A woodland explorer map can be bought from a [cartographer Villager](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cartographer) for 16-28 Emeralds and a Compass
- When exploring in survival mode, be aware that the Mansion from inside is very hostile and easy to get lost inside. Getting lost inside the Mansion will often result in death (and loss of items).
- Some screenshots:

The Mansion from outside:

[image: The Mansion]

The entrance hallway with the staircase:

[image: The Hallway]

Good luck exploring!

Comment: I had not heard about this update until just now.  Wow!  Thank you for all of the information!

Comment: I tramped to 3 different towns, talked to 3 different cartographers, got rid of more than 64 emeralds, and all they offered me was an "Ocean explorer map". So .. ?

Comment: @Blauhirn They sometimes offer a Ocean explorer map, and sometimes a Woodland one. Seems like you were extra unlucky..