# Where can I find chests in Woodland Mansions, and what can I find in them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I noticed, while playing my survival world in Minecraft snapshots, when exploring a Woodland Mansion, that some rooms had chests, especially the secret rooms (without entrances) I found.

**Which rooms contain chests and what can I find in them?** And a side question: Can I find any other valuable items inside?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288790/what-types-of-rooms-can-i-find-in-a-woodland-mansion-in-minecraft?noredirect=1&lq=1, related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288581/what-are-woodland-mansions-in-minecraft-1-11-where-can-i-find-them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of where can you find chests (with loot), and what you can find in them. I included links to screenshots:

- **[Sapling room](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/thumb/4/47/MansionSaplingRoom.png/250px-MansionSaplingRoom.png?version=5ab299ad43f4253213dddc9e80a39135)**. A normally accessible room with a bunch of dark oak saplings stacked in rows on the walls, and with a chest inside. And the chest contains... (drumroll) 25-30 dark oak saplings!
- **[Tree chopping room](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/thumb/1/1b/MansionTreeRoom2.png/250px-MansionTreeRoom2.png?version=fdf516918c1497579cebbaeb546c94be)**. A room sealed off from the hallway with a wall, leaving a empty indent in the hall. Contains a chest with an iron axe with efficiency 1.
- **[Wood archway room](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/thumb/4/42/MansionArches.png/250px-MansionArches.png?version=98e67360b5a46f7ee1943ca409e54213)**. A normally accessible room with a loot chest inside.
- **[Curved stairway room](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/thumb/5/56/MansionWindingStairs.png/250px-MansionWindingStairs.png?version=e2e86e63f6647aca6bd51605963d8ebc)**. A room with a staircase leading from a hallway to a dead end, where is a loot chest.
- **[Bedroom with loft](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/thumb/2/2b/MansionBedroom4.png/250px-MansionBedroom4.png?version=ddd726fc1bf6b179b00c5c0125db59a2)**. An interesting two-tiered bedroom, containing a sort of closet made of birch wood. A ladder near the entrance leads above to a loft with a loot chest.
- **[Arena](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/thumb/3/3c/MansionArena.png/250px-MansionArena.png?version=6a00b065ebc6fc8a471b3a7a9012f55c)**. A room with an arena/stage surrounded with dark oak fences in the center. A ladder leads up to an overhead loft with a loot chest.
- **[Gray banner room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXQut.png)**. An altar-like room with a cobblestone construction in the middle. Behind the construction is a loot chest.
- **[X room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqYKE.png)**, **[Clean chest room](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/thumb/0/0d/MansionSealedRoom2.png/250px-MansionSealedRoom2.png?version=67ec0085e72bc988bb39673ad69e4fa7)**, **[Fake End portal room](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/thumb/e/e4/MansionAltar2.png/250px-MansionAltar2.png?version=a88f10facfcaab9b996f2f637ce76b67)**. Secret rooms with no entrances and a loot chest.
- **[Roof-chest room](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/thumb/8/82/MansionSealedRoom1.png/250px-MansionSealedRoom1.png?version=89ad34ff45aa062c12ecc0dece100c77)**. An empty, secret room with a [small attic-like space](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/thumb/e/ea/MansionAttic.png/250px-MansionAttic.png?version=c1584a294ac5e4c48cbaf62fcb59a846) above it containing two loot chests.

All the loot chests have the same item generation rules - each chest contains 3 groups of 1–3, 1–4, and 3 item stacks. These items can spawn inside, ordered by frequency:

- **Rotten flesh, sting, bone, gunpowder** (**3-4** per chest, chance of **58%** to get them from a single chest)
- **Wheat, bread** (**0.5 - 1** per chest, chance **35%**)
- **Name tag** (**0.3** items per chest, chance **29%**)
- **Coal, redstone** (**0.75** per chest, chance **27%**)
- **Music disk 13, Cat, Golden apple, Diamond hoe** (**0.25** per chest, chance **22%**)
- **Beetroot, pumpkin, melon seeds** (**0.6** per chest, chance **19%**)
- **Iron ingot** (**0.5** per chest, chance **19%**)
- **Bucket** (**0.2** per chest, chance **19%**)
- **Enchanted book**, Chainmail chestplate (**0.15** per chest, chance **15%**)
- **Gold ingot** (**0.25** per chest, chance **10%**)
- **Diamond** chestplate (**0.08** per chest, chance **8%**)
- **Enchanted golden apple** (**0.03** per chest, chance **3%**)

The items where the number of items per chest times 100 equals the chance to obtain, will spawn in a maximum of one item per chest. In average, you will find 5 - 10 chests per Woodland Masnion.

For more informaion about rooms in woodland mansions, check out these links: **[A list of all rooms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288790/what-types-of-rooms-can-i-find-in-a-woodland-mansion-in-minecraft)**, or the **[Minecraft wiki article about Mansions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Woodland_mansion)**.