# Is the Cartographer villager rare or simply new in Minecraft 1.11?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It came as a name of a villager for me. It was the seed woodland mansion exactly like that and the closest sandstone village. I really want to know, am I just lucky I found him?

[image: Is it a villager name?]

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Are you asking if anyone has ever come across a villager asking for paper in exchange for emeralds?

Comment: This is a cartographer (transliterating that Cyrillic, roughly: `K`=c, `p`=r, `r`=g, `ø`=ph, so `c a r t o g r a ph`), they're [new in 1.11](http://www.pcgamer.com/minecraft-exploration-update-adds-cartographers-and-the-illagers/).

Comment: @DanBron - You should add that as an answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

**Cartographer Villagers are as rare as any other type of Villagers.** They offer new items and have a new set of shops, including a [Exploration map](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Exploration_Map), used to find [Woodland mansions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288581/what-are-woodland-mansions-in-minecraft-1-11-where-can-i-find-them) or Ocean temples. A map will cost significantly more than other items.